# angular-scroll : Jasmine Unit Test fail, need fixture html in the unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maven, jasmine, fixtures

I insert angular-scroll plugin in my angular app.
I insert anchors in pages, targeted in controller methodes with the method scrollToElementAnimated.
It run well in the app, but all my controller methodes are tested with Jasmine tests (run with maven : com.github.searls.jasmine-maven-plugin V1.3.1.4).

Tests fails with the error :

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'd(e).getBoundingClientRect') in
>   http://localhost:56972/src/main/webapp/vendor/angular-scroll.min-0.7.2.js

I think the problem is that, JS tests don't have DOM elements, and when the test pass on the line :

```
$document.scrollToElementAnimated(angular.element(document.getElementById('myAnchorId')));
```

,the methode document.getElementById('myDivIdToScroll') return undefined.

How can I tell the JS Unit tests to load a fixture page or a mock for the getElementById method or directly for the scrollToElementAnimated methode?

PS : I've seen a plugin (here) : jasmine-jquery.js that can load HTML fixtures for Jasmine Unit test but:

- This plugin need Jquery and I dont have it in m'y app (angular jglite only)
- I do not know if this will solve the problem that I have with the angular-scroll method call.
- ( I even though try to use it but I didn't succeed to run it in maven jasmine plugin... ^^')

Thank you for your help

Comment: I succeed to run jasmine-jquery.js plugin. \o/

Comment: For information, the jasmine-jquery.js plugin pb was a version pb : 
 -> Last jasmine-jquery plugin version (2.1) need last jasmine version (2.3)
 -> Last Jasmine version is used by last jasmine maven plugin (2.0)
 -> Last jasmine maven plugin need maven 3.0...

But i'm stuck with maven 2.0. So I used :
 -> jasmine-maven-plugin V 1.3.1.4
 -> jasmine-jquery.js V1.7.0
And it's work ^^

But this way need jquery (in scope test). If anybody have a way to add fixture to angular jasmine unit tests without jquery, I would like it ;)